# EC2 instances cannot ping each other

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have 2 EC2 Ubuntu instances. They are sharing same VPC, subnet and Security Group. Instances' firewall was turnoff. But I still can't ping each other by private IP. How to allow those instances ping each other?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In the security group, add "Custom ICMP" rule for "Echo Request" -- or -- "All ICMP Traffic" -- and as the source IP, instead of an address or block, add the security group's identifier, sg-xxxxxxxx.

Simply being in the same security group doesn't mean the instances can communicate among themselves.  It only means they follow the same set of rules... but security group membership is a source attribute as well, on traffic originating from instances that are members of the group.

Hence, the above.

Comment: @ZackyPickholz a common error is to inadvertently select ICMP Echo *Reply*, since it has historically been the first option in the drop-down list.  ICMP Echo *Request* is the only thing you should need on the inbound rules of a security group to allow pinging.  The statefulness of securitu groups implicitly allows the reply to any explicitly allowed request.  Enabling only ICMP Echo Request is my standard configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Michael, you're 100% right. Allowing only ICMP Echo Request on the security group works as security group rules are transitive.

Comment: Thank you.. I allowed "All ICMP Traffic" and pointed source to my security group . Worked like charm :)

Comment: @ZackyPickholz Your comment spot on, choosing 'Echo Reply' is a common mistake.

Answer (score 3):

if it is windows instance, then you need to enable rule in firewall.
And also need to add inbound rule for your private CIDR range atleast

[image: firewall rule]

[image: CIDR]

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new rule to you security group (see the third line in the screenshot below), then your two ec2 vms will be able to ping each other.

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what is "like this" with a few words?

Comment: you should add new rule on you securıty group. focus third line (Custom ICMP, Echo Request, N/A)